# How do I prepare multidimensional array from php mysql query for jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, autocomplete

I am trying to set up a jQuery autocomplete that uses results from a PHP MySql query.

I have the basic autocomplete working for a 1-d array of values, but can't get it to work with a 2-d array. I want to use a 2-d array so that one column populates the auto-complete and one column populates the value submitted in the form (either through the value of the input or another hidden value).

I know the format needs to look like this after using `json_encode()`: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]` but can't quite get it to look like that...

The code below is not my working code but it represents what I would like to do: display the names in the *autocomplete* field, but submit the *page_id*.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT name, page_id FROM table WHERE city = '{$location}' ORDER BY name";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[] = $row;
}

<script>
  $( function() {
    var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
    $( "#input" ).autocomplete({
      source: array
    });
  } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to distinguish value and label, you must provide an array of objects, as described in the jQuery autocomplete documentation:

> #### source
>
> **Array**: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

As you are looking for that second option you should in PHP prepare that exact structure. This you can do as follows:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[] = array(
        "label" => $row['name'],
        "value" => $row['page_id']
    );
}
```

This adds so-called *associative arrays* into the normal (*indexed*) array. `json_encode` translates *associative arrays* into object notation.

Comment: Thank you so much, trincot. This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew what the structure needed to be but wasn't exactly sure how to do it (I tried many different variations to create the array). Thanks!